# VirtualHost Configuration causing issues

Tags: apache, virtualhost

I am quite new to VirtualHosts, 
My use case is: 
The domain mobc.in should be redirected to /var/www/html/mobc 
And all other requests should be redirected to /var/www/html

The configuration that I am using it is

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
     DocumentRoot /var/www/html/mobc
     ServerName www.mobc.in
     ServerAlias mobc.in *.mobc.in
     ErrorLog logs/mobc.in-error_log
    CustomLog logs/mobc.in-access_log common
</VirtualHost>
```

This is not serving the purpose and even mobc.in is being redirected to /var/www/html

Kindly help me.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the fist virtualhost tags and contents. Just use the 2nd one and use the default documentroot in httpd.conf

Comment: Hey, I tried this earlier, but faced an issue. Say My IP is xx.xx.xx.xx . When I remove the first Virtualhost tags, although mobc.in redirects to the required directory, xx.xx.xx.xx/mobc doesn't work. 

Do you have any suggestion on that?

Comment: to get xx.xx.xx.xx/mobc to work, you will need to use the Alias option.

    # Alias: Maps web paths into filesystem paths and is used to
    # access content that does not live under the DocumentRoot.
    # Example:
    # Alias /webpath /full/filesystem/path